# Integrate Qt into prewritten Application/Framework

Tags: qt, opengl, glut, qglwidget

I have a small visualization framework written in c++ and want to use Qt to have a proper GUI and control over my visualizations to interact with them. currently, I am using GLUT to create a window and draw a view in it. so everything I do is initialize an object of the class Visualization which does everything for me: holding model and views. the view itself holds a controller to process user input and manipulate the model. my main loop looks like this:

```
Visualization* vis = new Visualization();
vis->createModel("some_file.txt");
vis->createView("unknown");

// ...

void demo_app::display()
{
  // clear the framebuffer
  glClearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  vis.update(); // looks for dirty scenes to update
  vis.render(); // draws all views which are stored in vis

  glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

with GLUT I have a single window in which I arrange multiple views. when I order the view to draw during the main loop I can execute glCommands and everything is fine.

so now my problem is I want to use Qt with several windows (`QDialogs`+`QGLWidgets`). I am familiar with Qt and I already ported the framework to Qt. but the problem is that I have to do too much Qt integration within the framework and this is not what I want. I want to control the visualization with Qt and its GUI elements, but the draw call for a view should be made by my Visualization class as shown by the GLUT example. So there must be a way to give an inherited `QGLWidget` a pointer to a view object and whenever the view should be drawn the widget has to call `makeCurrent()` so the glCommands can draw on the context.
I also can use a texture in which my view paints the current scene and then draw the texture in the paintGL or `glDraw()` function of the `QGLWidget`, but how can I tell the Widget to `update()` when the view has no knowledge about it.
I will emulate the main loop with a `QTimer` set to 0. all I want to do is to be able to trigger the rendering of the `QGLWidget` from inside my framework. any suggestion? links? examples?

Answer (score 0):

> So there must be a way to give an inherited QGLWidget a pointer to a view object and whenever the view should be drawn

If you call `demo_app::display()` from within `QGLWidget::paintGL`, it will work and will draw scene onto `QGLWidget` context. However, this will use `QGLWidget`'s context, so you'll need to move All initialization functions into `QGLWidget`. I don't remember whether OpenGL objects can be shared across context, but won't be really surprised if this can't be done.

> but how can i tell the Widget to update() when the view has no knowledge about it.

Well, add pointer to `QWidget` to the view and call `QWidget->update()`. Should be obvious.

**If you want to draw qt widgets from within GLUT-based window...**

I.e. if you want to "embed" Qt widgets into GLUT window.

Every Qt widget has `render` method. You can use this method to draw widget onto any `QPaintDevice` or using any `QPainter`.

So, to draw widget from within the framework, you'll have to provide one of those to the widget and call render manually.

You'll also have to forward mouse and keyboard event from the framework and convert them into Qt events.

That should be doable but it will be major pain to implement.

Also see [EmbeddedDialogs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/demos-embeddeddialogs.html) demo and [QGraphicsProxyWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsproxywidget.html/).

**If you simply want to use GUI widgets in addition to glut window, without embedding them into glut window...**

Wrap everything related to your framework and glut messages into `QObject`, and put glut message handling into this object's slot. Connect this slot to a timer running with `0` timeout.

Example from my code (uses SDL):

```
class Game: public QObject{
Q_OBJECT
protected:
    void processSdlEvents();
...
protected slots:
    void onGameEnd();
    void timerSlot();
...
};

Game::Game(/*arguments*/ ...){
...
    gameTimer = new QTimer(this);
    gameTimer->setSingleShot(false);
    gameTimer->setInterval(0);
    connect(gameTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timerSlot()));
...
}

void Game::timerSlot(){
    processSdlEvents();
    update();
    render();
}

void Game::processSdlEvents(){
    SDL_Event event;
    QList<GameEventHandler*> eventHandlers = findChildren<GameEventHandler*>();
    /*WARNING: This is NOT an infinite loop. */
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0){
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT){
            emit gameEnded();
            continue;
        }
        bool processed = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < eventHandlers.size(); i++){
            if (eventHandlers[i]->processEvent(&event)){
                processed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (processed)
            continue;
        for (int i = 0; i < joysticks.size(); i++){
            if (joysticks[i]->processEvent(&event)){
                processed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        /*if (processed)
            continue;*/
    }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    int result = 0;
    try{
        Game game;
        QObject::connect(&game, SIGNAL(gameEnded()), &app, SLOT(quit()));
        game.start();
        result = app.exec();
    }
    catch(const QString& s){
        reportException(s);
    }
    catch(std::exception& e){
        reportException(e);
    }
    catch(...){
        reportException();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Please note that processSdlEvents is NOT an infinite loops. It gets called once in a while and processes all events received since the last call and then terminates.

In this scenario your framework specific functions are called from within Qt main loop.

You could also probably do it other way around and call Qt-specific functions from main loop in your own framework (using either `QEventLoop` class or `QApplication::processEvents()`) but it might be less reliable and I haven't tried that myself.

Comment: i don't want to call my `demo_app::display()` from within a QGLWidget. this should be executed in the main loop and than the views draw themselves. i don't want the `paintGL()` trigger my main display function because there should be multiple `QGLWidgets` with different views.

Comment: @iam_peter: "this should be executed in the main loop" Um, no, that's incorrect and there's no real reason to call "display" manually from within main loop (**maybe** unless you're using fullscreen application). Qt doesn't work this way. Widget calls `paint`/`paintGL` when necessary. If you want to repaint continuously, call `update` continuously. Continuously repainting multiple widgets from within main loop will simply waste CPU and won't do anything useful.

Comment: the display function determines which view should be redrawn because of some model changes. this mechanism should not be directed to Qt this should be done by my Visualization class that is the reason i call display/update in the main loop. during the display call views are redrawn accordingly this should not be triggered by Qt. Everything Qt should do is inform my view about user interaction so setting the view dirty. then my scheduler (=Visualization) should trigger everything else.

Comment: @iam_peter: I disagree. In my opinion, you're "putting the cart before the horse". There's no reason to stick to this design, especially when framework you're using doesn't "like it". Just update corresponding view when model changes, that should be enough.